# how to view the interfaces for each connection in the nat table?

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I've used `cat proc/net/ip_conntrack` to view all the connections related to the NAT table on the device. But this doesn't give any information with respect to the interface used and the type of nat for each connection available on the device.

Is there any way to view the interface and nat type for each connections along with the details available in the above mentioned file?